# Postgresql doesn't show column 'Member of' in CMD

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, cmd

I've created some simple users as members of a group and I did this with 'postgres' user. The issue I'm facing is when I use commands like '\du' or '\dg' or any similar command, doesn't display the 'Member of' column in CMD and I have only a maximum of 3 columns: 'Role name', 'Attributes' and 'Description'. My Postgresql version is 16.1. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you start [`psql` with `-E` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-OPTION-ECHO-HIDDEN), it will show you how it collects the data for the `member of` column. You can run those queries yourself: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2_7I4ely)

```
create role ted superuser;
create role bob;
grant ted to bob;

SELECT r.rolname,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
WHERE r.rolname !~ '^pg_'
ORDER BY 1;
```

| rolname | memberof |
| --- | --- |
| bob | {ted} |
| postgres | {} |
| ted | {} |

Aside from overlooking that you need to scroll to the side, I don't see how or why it wouldn't show the column especially since `\du+` should list `Description` *after* `Member of`. You might want to make sure your `psql` is the same version as the db you're connecting to.

Comment: Thanks Zegarek for your time, I checked different things but it wasn't resolved. I used your code as an alternative solution and it works for me now.

Comment: @MaryamMirfazaelian When you start `psql`, it should open the session with info about psql version (you can also run `psql --version`) and separately the version of the db you're connecting to - do those match, and what version of psql is it? Is the column gone entirely when you run `\du+`, or is it just empty all the time?